# Syntax error on the last line in the ansible playbook

Tags: syntax, ansible

All,
My playbook is almost ready. Only the last line with alias is giving me issues. I tried to look at what I am doing wrong in the yaml syntax checker but still not able to find it. Any clue what I am doing wrong? I tried escaping the forward slash but still no luck :(

I am bad at finding the syntax errors in general. So appreciate any clues you folks can provide in finding the problem.

```
  tasks:
    - name: Create a KMS key for using the aws cli
      command: 'aws kms create-key --profile="{{ aws_profile }}" --region="{{ aws_region }}"'
      register: newkeydetails

    - name: Display the values for the variable output
      set_fact: newkeydetails="{{ newkeydetails.stdout | from_json }}"

    - name: Display the value of keyid
      debug:
        msg: "{{ newkeydetails.KeyMetadata.KeyId }}"

    - name: Create a alias name for KMS key  using the aws cli
      command: 'aws kms create-alias --alias-name 'alias/anothernewkeydetailskey' --target-key-id '"{{ newkeydetails.KeyMetadata.KeyId }}"' --profile="{{ aws_profile }}" --region="{{ aws_region }}"'
```

Comment: Might this issue be due to not escaping your single quotes in the last line? Perhaps the following might work?

`'aws kms create-alias --alias-name "alias/anothernewkeydetailskey" --target-key-id "{{ newkeydetails.KeyMetadata.KeyId }}" --profile="{{ aws_profile }}" --region="{{ aws_region }}"`

Comment: Also, if you are wondering what I am trying to do. I am trying to use the command module to create a new AWS KMS key and then, create the alias for the key.

Comment: Appreciate your help Andrew. Yes you are correct. This is what got me working:

Comment: command: 'aws kms create-alias --alias-name "alias/anothernewkeydetailskey" --target-key-id "{{ newkeydetails.KeyMetadata.KeyId }}" --profile="{{ aws_profile }}" --region="{{ aws_region }}"'

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the issue here was due to the usage of single quotes in the last line, as they were not escaped, resulting in parsing errors.

The working solution involves removing unnecessary quotes, resulting in the following:

`'aws kms create-alias --alias-name "alias/anothernewkeydetailskey" --target-key-id "{{ newkeydetails.KeyMetadata.KeyId }}" --profile="{{ aws_profile }}" --region="{{ aws_region }}"`